# onServiceConnected is not called after bindService after 3 or 4 launch of application

Tags: android, android-service, bindservice, onserviceconnected

I am facing a weird issue .On launch of my app I am connecting Activity to  service.Service connection is getting established successfully and  works fine in Samsung galaxy S5 and other devices too.But in other devices like Moto E , Moto G etc it works only 2 or 3 time after 3 or 4 launch it dose not works at all.
communication between service and Activity is achieved using massenger. I observed  that when my app  stops working `onServiceConnected` is not called but even in this case bindservice returns true. Similar issue Is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591136/onserviceconnected-sometimes-not-called-after-bindservice-on-some-devices) but no answer

This is how I bind the service to an Activity

```
    startService(new Intent(this,MyService.class));
    boolean bound = bindService(new Intent(this,MyService.class), serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);//bound is true everytime
```

Below is onBind Of MyService

```
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    return messenger.getBinder();
}
```

Here messenger is an instance of Messenger ,to communicate between activity and service.

Comment: Do you unbind your when the activity is paused/stoped?

Comment: no ..I don't think it is required

Comment: @Shakeeb_Ayaz, Take a look at my answer

Answer (score 1):

You should do `unbind` when your activity is paused or destroyed. Take a look [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html).

Edit:
If you want your service to continue running, start it with `startService` and make it a **foreground** one. Than you can bind and unbind your activity when resuming and pausing. I used this approach when was doing my thesis that was a media player for android :)

Comment: Its media player application.So I should not stop playing until user stops it